# Import Product Programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cron, importexport

For product import,

I used to create a CSV file from the text file (from customer) via programming. Then I place it in `var/import` folder

**Now, For Magento 1.9**

My code was :

```
$profile = Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile');
$profile->load(7);  (7 for products)
$profile->run();
```

My all product are imported successfully.

**The same way Now I am trying for Magento 2.3**

I have successfully created CSV file from the text file (from customer) via programming.
Also from **Admin** > **System** > **Data transfer** > **Scheduled import/export** > **New Scheduled Import**
I have created one "scheduled import" for product.

Now, Please help me, how can I run it via programming. like (`$profile->run();`)

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://meetanshi.com/blog/import-product-data-programmatically-in-magento-2/

Comment: Thanks for helping. Actually I require to only call  (Admin > System > Data transfer > Scheduled import/export > New Scheduled Import ) as per my prepared codding. So I can't use https://meetanshi.com/blog/import-product-data-programmatically-in-magento-2/  .   Please help me if Magento2.3 have some similar type of functions like : $profile->run();